# Replace consecutive white spaces with a single space

Tags: java

Using Java, how can I replace all consecutive white spaces with a single space, in an elegant and simple way?

I am aware of `str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` but this replaces `\n` and other things too. I only want to replace multiple  one after another with a single .

Comment: So change the regex to only include space.

Answer (score 2):

Most regex flavors considers `\n` as whitespace. Same about `\r` or `\t`.

If you want to replace only one or more `" "` the simply use `replaceAll(" +", " ")`

Comment: `yourAnswer.replaceAll("Most","All")` ??? :)  I've never heard of one that didn't.